# How to prevent inheritance from breaking all dependencies in OOP manner without instanceof or typecasting?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

We are billing all seats in an airplane. Initially we had a discount per seat.
Assume we had a class `Discount`, and a `seat-billing` and `audit` code depended on it.

```
class Discount {

    private int discountId; // unique key stored in database

    public int getDiscountId() {
        return discountId;
    }

    public List<Seat> getListOfSeatsWithDiscount() {

    }

    public int getDiscountPercentPerSeat() { return 10; }

}

class SeatBill {
    public void billPerSeat() {
        for (each seat object) {
            // fetch discountObject from database.
            Discount d;
            // get list of seats with discounts, and for each of such seats
            seatObject.totalCost = seatObject.totalCost * (100 - d.getDiscountPercentPerSeat())/100;
        }
    }
}
```

Then we have an audit class which cares about discounted seats.

```
class Audit {

    public void audit(Discount id) {
        // fetch discount object from database given discount id.
        for (seat in d.getListOfSeatsWithDiscount()) {
            // log all the seats.
        }
    }
}
```

Now airplane management decides to add another discount -> monthly discount for holiday season.
Thus we created an abstract class `Discount` and created `DiscountPerSeat` and `DiscountPerMonth`.

```
abstract class Discount {
    private int discountId; // unique key stored in database

    public int getDiscountId() {
        return discountId;
    }
}

class DiscountPerSeat extends Discount {


    public List<Seat> getListOfSeatsWithDiscount() {

    }

    // returns 10% discount on each seat reserved.
    public int getDiscountPercentPerSeat() { return 10; }

}

class DiscountPerMonth extends Discount {

    public boolean checkIfMonthIsValid(int month) {
        return month == 12;
    }

    // returns 10% discount on monthly bill
    public int getDiscountPercentPerMonth() { return 10; } 
}
```

The monthly bill code will now change.

```
class MonthlyBill {

    public int monthlyBillPerPersonOrCompany(int id) {
        int totalCostPerEntity = gettotalCost(id);
        // fetch discount object from database
        // apply discount if 'current month' is december'
        totalCostPerEntity = totalCostPerEntity * (100 - (disCountPerMonth.getDiscountPercentPerMonth()))/100
    }
}
```

Now my question is:

1. Audit class is broken because `getListOfSeatsWithDiscount` is moved into its subclasss of abstract method discount. How to fix it without typecaseting/instanceof ?
2. SeatBill class is broken, since abstract class Discount does not support getDiscountPercentPerSeat. How to fix this without typecasting / instanceof  ?
3. MonthlyBill will fetch discount object from database. Once again how to resolve this issue in an OOP way without relying on instance of ?

Basically a whole lot of dependencies are broken in code base because code relies on specific methods of subclasses such as `getListOfSeats` or `getValidMonth` etc which cannot be abstracted to the base class.

Please let me know a common solution / design pattern to such refactoring.

Comment: Why do discounts of both types need to be in a single collection?  Why not have separate getSeatDiscounts and getMonthlyDiscounts methods?  Regarding the database, why not make separate tables for each discount type?

Comment: I don't think we can fix this, because it's a design issue.  You have an `Audit` class that assumes that a `Discount` applies to a list of seats.  You've now redefined `Discount` so that the assumption is no longer valid.  So what is `Audit` supposed to do now?  That's something only you can answer.  There's no "common solution" to this, and no "design pattern" you can just apply that will fix everything.  It requires knowledge of the application you're trying to design, and your design will need rethinking.

Answer (score 1):

To solve problem 1, you need to declare `public abstract List<Seat> getListOfSeatsWithDiscount();` in Discount. Then you, need to define the `getListOfSeatsWithDiscount()` in DiscountPerMonth too. If Audit is supposed to work just with DiscountPerSeat, just use DiscountPerSeat (not Discount) in Audit.

To solve problem 2, you need to declare `public abstract int getDiscount();` in Discount and rename the methods in both DiscountPerSeat and DiscountPerMonth to getDiscount().

Problem 3 should be solved by the solution to problem 2.